# Maximum setlocal recursion level reached & endlocal. Workaround?

Tags: batch-file, recursion, cmd, batch-processing, command-prompt

I have a block of code that is being executed anywhere from 0-100,000 times. The problematic block appears as so:

```
FOR /R %%f IN (*.*) DO (
  CLS
  ECHO Del 2.0
  ECHO Files Done^: !FILES_DONE! / !FILES_TOTAL!
  ECHO Missing^: !FILES_MISSING!
  SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
  SET "FILES_TEMP=%%f"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF EXIST "!FILES_TEMP!" (
    !DELITE! -p 13 -q "!FILES_TEMP!" >NUL
    SET /A FILES_DONE += 1
  ) ELSE (
    SET /A FILES_MISSING += 1
  )
)
```

In this block: `!FILES_DONE!`, `!FILES_TOTAL!`, and `!FILES_MISSING!` are all integer vars.

`!DELITE!` is a reference to an executable: "!CD!\_sdelete.exe" where "!CD!" is the root folder the batch is executed in.

Note: be advised that the DelayedExpansion being turned on/off is necessary as I need to capture file names that may or may not have special characters such as: "!" and "^".

So my question is: how can I reformat this block of code to not throw the Maximum Recursion Level Reached error? (I realize how frequently this question is asked and this is only half my question, so bear with me please)

Secondly, can someone explain how this block of code would act in terms of local environment?

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R %%f IN (*.*) DO (
  ECHO !FILES_DONE! / !FILES_TOTAL!
  ENDLOCAL & (
    SET "FILES_TEMP=%%f"
  )
  [etc...]
)
```

For instance, once it loops through the code once, will the 'endlocal' still be in effect or will it be reinstated since it's a new loop? Also, will it contribute to the Maximum Setlocal Level Reached?

`###########################################################################################`

Del 2.0 - Full File Contents For Anyone That Wants To Use It
Note: If anyone wants an updated copy of the Del Batch, message me; it is currently on V3.0-R0, you need to use the [sdelete.exe command-line utility from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sdelete.aspx). I may end up hosting this on a site as a free extension for anyone that wants a secure deletion program.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TITLE Del 2.0
GOTO PRECHECK

:PRECHECK
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Checking...
IF NOT EXIST "!CD!\To-Do" (
  ECHO To-Do Folder Not Found
  ECHO.
  ECHO Nothing To Delete
  PAUSE >NUL
  GOTO END
)
IF NOT EXIST "!CD!\_sdelete.exe" (
  ECHO SDelete Program Not Found
  ECHO.
  ECHO Core File "_sdelete.exe" Missing
  PAUSE >NUL
  GOTO END
) ELSE (
  ATTRIB +S +H "!CD!\_sdelete.exe" >NUL
)
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
GOTO SETVARS

:SETVARS
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Writing Variables...
SET TAB=    
SET FILES_TEMP=0
SET FILES_TOTAL=0
SET FILES_DONE=0
SET FILES_MISSING=0
SET ROOTCD=!CD!
SET HOMECD=!CD!\To-Do
SET DELITE="!CD!\_sdelete.exe"
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
GOTO START

:START
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Starting...
ATTRIB -S -H ** /S /D
CD To-Do
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Counting Files...
FOR /R %%f IN (**) DO (
  CLS
  SET /A FILES_TOTAL += 1
  ECHO Del 2.0
  ECHO Files Found^: !FILES_TOTAL!
)
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
GOTO ERASEFILES

:ERASEFILES
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Erasing Files...
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R %%f IN (*.*) DO (
  SET "FILES_TEMP=%%f"
  CALL :SUBERASE
)
GOTO FINISHERASE

:SUBERASE
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Files Done^: %FILES_DONE% / %FILES_TOTAL%
ECHO Missing^: %FILES_MISSING%
IF EXIST "%FILES_TEMP%" (
  %DELITE% -p 13 -q "%FILES_TEMP%" >NUL
  SET /A FILES_DONE += 1
) ELSE (
  SET /A FILES_MISSING += 1
)
EXIT /B

:FINISHERASE
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Files Done^: !FILES_DONE! / !FILES_TOTAL!
ECHO Missing^: !FILES_MISSING!
TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK >NUL
GOTO CLEANUP

:CLEANUP
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Cleaning Up...
IF !FILES_MISSING! EQU 0 (
  FOR /D %%f in (*.*) DO (
    SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
    SET "FILES_TEMP=%%f"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    RD "!FILES_TEMP!" /S /Q >NUL
  )
)
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
GOTO END

:END
CLS
ECHO Del 2.0
ECHO Complete^^!
TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK >NUL
EXIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) disabled using [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R %%f IN (*.*) DO (
  SET "FILES_TEMP=%%f"
  CALL :doAll
)
goto :skipSubroutine

:doAll
  CLS
  ECHO Del 2.0
  ECHO Files Done^: %FILES_DONE% / %FILES_TOTAL%
  ECHO Missing^: %FILES_MISSING%
  IF EXIST "%FILES_TEMP%" (
    %DELITE% -p 13 -q "%FILES_TEMP%" >NUL
    SET /A FILES_DONE += 1
  ) ELSE (
    SET /A FILES_MISSING += 1
  )
goto :eof

:skipSubroutine
```

If `FILES_TEMP` variable *requires* [Delayed Expansion enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) then the `:doAll` subroutine could look as follows (Note that `ENDLOCAL` command is used twice to update variables `FILES_DONE` and `FILES_MISSING` correctly in script scope):

```
:doAll
  CLS
  ECHO Del 2.0
  ECHO Files Done^: %FILES_DONE% / %FILES_TOTAL%
  ECHO Missing^: %FILES_MISSING%
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF EXIST "!FILES_TEMP!" (
    %DELITE% -p 13 -q "!FILES_TEMP!" >NUL
    ENDLOCAL
    SET /A FILES_DONE += 1
  ) ELSE (
    ENDLOCAL
    SET /A FILES_MISSING += 1
  )
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it immediately and accept it if it proves to work without a hitch. Instead of using the "goto :eof" I could use "goto :release" when ":release" contains "exit /b" right? "exit" would kill the script whereas "exit /b" would terminate the call? Sorry about the rather elementary question, I'm very unfamiliar with CALL

Comment: @JoeBro please read **EOF** paragraph in http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html - `goto :eof` and `exit /B` are equivalent if [Command Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled. Please **do not** declare `:eof` label anywhere in your script to stay on the safe side.

Comment: It works perfectly! I edited the supplied code to "play nice" with the rest of the script; but thank you, I'll accept this as the answer as soon as I have the other sub-questions answered; but that solves the bulk of the problem. Could someone at least upvote this for me? Yeah, I remember that :eof actually signifies the end-of-the-file instead of an actual label; thanks for informing me about them being equivalent, it's very useful information.

Comment: The only "missing"/"skipped" files (I added that feature to make debugging files with "!" and "^" easier) now are only a result of directory names being too long which is reasonable and manageable and is highly uncommon IME. So thanks once more! It truly does work perfectly.